# Why we use mysqli_init() and mysqli_real_connect() if we have mysqli_connect() function in php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to php and doing some experiments on the following three functions:

1. **mysqli_connect()**
2. **mysqli_real_connect()**
3. **mysqli_init()**

As we know that PHP provides two ways to connect to mysql server.

1. **Object Oriented mysqli class**
2. **Procedural mysqli**

**Question one:** When we do something like that

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host','username','password','database');
```

It means we started connection to mysql server, so why then using the following statement even we already connected the mysql database server.

```
$mysqli->init(void);
```

**Question two:** When we do something like that

```
mysqli_init(void);
```

So, whether it automatically get the mysql object ? Should we use **mysqli_connect()** function before it or it automatically generates mysql server object internally by php ? Should we call this **mysqli_init()** function without any **mysqli_connect()** function ? Whether **mysqli_init()** automatically gets the mysql server object internally ?

**Question three:**

When we have

```
mysqli_connect();
```

then why we use

```
mysqli_init();
```

and

```
mysqli_real_connect();
```

Why php added the **mysqli_init()** and **mysqli_real_connect()** function even **mysqli_connect()** is available ? Where the **mysqli_init()** and **mysqli_real_connect()** functions are useful instead of **mysqli_connect()** ?

What is the difference between them ?

Can anyone tell ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the **mysqli_init()** method that is placed in mysqli class ?

Comment: Whether mysqli_init() creates mysql object internally withour mysqli_Connect() function ?

Comment: Why it fails when i do something like that **$x = new mysqli(), $x->init()** ??

Comment: Because `init` is a plain function, it is __not__ method of object.

Comment: If you don't need to change any connection options, you just use `mysqli_connect(...)` or `new mysqli(...)`. If you want to change some options, you should at least look at the examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php).

Comment: Please one more thing. Should we use **mysqli_connect()** before **mysqli_init()** or no ? Whether **mysqli_init()** function is independent from **mysqli_connect()** and it returns the mysql object internally without the reference of any function. I am asking this question because **mysqli_init()** has no parameters that is why i am confused that from where it returns the mysql object, whether internally or from any where ?